# What does fetching mean in computer science?

Tags: sql, database, fetch

In some contexts I think it means "transferring data from one place to another". For example, using python's sqlalchemy package the data from a sql database is "fetched" in order to be used by python.

Are there other meanings and contexts?

Comment: fetching *verb* go for and then bring back (someone or something).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fetching is commonly used to describe a transfer from a storage system of a "slower" kind into a "faster" one:

- Fetching data from disk into a memory buffer
- Fetching data from memory into CPU register
- Fetching data from RDBMS into memory,

and so on.